# ElasticSearch mapping type Twitter coordinates

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there anyway to mapping type this structure for Spatial Search ElasticSearch:

```
"coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            100.41404641,
            5.37384675
        ]
    },
```

I was wondering to use this as it comes from my MongoDB for geo-point type without splitting them into lat and long fields like existing tutorials and examples.

This structure is what Twitter API streams as a default, so I could save it as "location":{ "lat": 100.41, "long": 5.34 } into MongoDB. But before adding extra fields to my database or changing things I want to make sure there is no way to use this structure for spatial search in ElasticSearch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ElasticSearch documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) it is possible to have an array of lat and long in the mapping as a Geo point type.

Mapping:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Format in [lon, lat], note, the order of lon/lat here in order to conform with GeoJSON.

```
PUT my_index/my_type/4
{
  "text": "Geo-point as an array",
  "location": [ -71.34, 41.12 ] 
}
```

Other examples for Geo-point datatype:

- Geo-point expressed as a string with the format: "lat,lon"
- Geo-point expressed as a geohash
- Geo-point expressed as an array with the format: [ lon, lat]